# GIT Cross platform Windows VS MacOS image file sizes / binary differs

Tags: git, macos, webpack, imagemin, mozjpeg

I'm sharing a project between MacOS and Windows users anytime making changes with JS or SCSS files we run webpack (used gulp previously) for production. After running webpack untouched image file sizes differ. They look the same but binary is different causing the smallest changes in js or scss file to be pushed with 200+ images.

```js
// webpack.mix.js
new ImageminPlugin({
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
  plugins: [
    imageminMozjpeg({
      quality: 80
    })
  ],
}),
```

```js
//git config
core.autocrlf=false
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using exactly the same versions of `mozjpeg` on both systens?  Where are you getting them from on each platform?  Are you using the versions built by the NPM module or some system version?

Comment: Yes, same version anytime we see our package.json change we just run npm install. We also use the same version of node and npm.